# Sequelize counting associated entries with separate

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to count the associated entries using the separate attribute in my includes to improve performance (without it the request it's taking 5s). But I'm receiving the following error:

"message": "missing FROM-clause entry for table "likedPosts""

Sorry for bad english, it's not my first. I hope you understand and can help me.

My code:

```js
@Query((returns) => [Post], {
  nullable: true
})
async getAllFeedPostsByUserId(@Arg('user_id') user_id: number): Promise < Post[] > {
  const result = await Post.findAll({
    attributes: {
      include: [
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("likedPosts.feed_post")), "likesAmount"]
      ]
    },
    include: [{
      model: LikedPosts,
      as: 'likedPosts',
      attributes: [],
      separate: true,

    }, ]
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think group is must to count entries.

```
Post.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('likedPosts.feed_post')), 'likesAmount']] 
    }, 

    include: [{
        model: LikedPosts, 
        attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['likedPosts.feed_post'] // groupBy is necessary else it will generate only 1 record with all rows count
})
```

I can see `seperate`

[separate desc](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v3.23.3/lib/model.js#L1306)

To elaborate: by default, to retrieve the related model instance, Sequelize will use a SQL JOIN. By enabling separate, Sequelize will perform a separate query for each of the associated models, and join the resulting documents in code (instead of letting the database perform the join).

Comment: I tried to add group but the error persist. I think the problem is the separate attribute, without it the count is working.

Comment: added some info about seperate

Comment: I understood that the separate will not let me create the count that way. But I don't know other way to do this with sequelize